# get data from internal JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

Hey i want to get the data from my json file and then display it in html, but first i will just console.log it. how do i exactly do that??
the json file will be updated as its the users input

**varer.json**

[{"id":"aa","varer":"aa","pris":""},{"id":"aa","varer":"aa","pris":""}]

**varer-controller**

```
const varerModel = require("./../models/varer");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/getproducts", (req, res) =>{
    var products = JSON.parse(varerModel)    
    console.log(products)
    res.send(products)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `JSON.parse` as it's already a `JSON` and can be directly used.

Comment: okay thanks, what should i write then var products  = ???       How do i get the data from the varer.json file?

Comment: You can directly log the name without assigning it to a variable.
Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicpopover-material-demo-forked-kmui0?file=/index.js

Comment: thank you:) its working now